# Content security policy in ssl.conf file does not work

Tags: apache, web-applications, content-security-policy

Project that I'm currently working on recently got this error when accessed with firefox browser and google chrome.

The error in google chrome :

```
Refused to load the image 'https://mydomain2.mysubdomain2.co.id/myimage.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' *.mydomain1.co.id:* data: blob:".
```

Because of that, I edit content-security-policy in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file to allow `img-src` from every URL that contains `mysubdomain2.co.id` in the web server.

Before :

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src blob: http: data: https:'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' *.mydomain1.co.id:* data: blob:;"
```

After :

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "default-src blob: http: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' *.mydomain1.co.id:* *.mysubdomain2.co.id* data: blob:;"
```

I append `*.mysubdomain2.co.id*` after `*.mysubdomain1.co.id:*` in the `img-src`

Then I stopped the `httpd` service then start the `httpd` service again

```
sudo systemctl stop httpd.service
sudo systemctl start httpd.service
```

I checked the `httpd.service` status with `sudo systemctl status httpd.service` before I stop the service, after I stop the service, and after I start the service, and the command worked as I expected. The `httpd.service` Started, stopped, and active again.

But I still got this error

```
Refused to load the image 'https://mydomain2.mysubdomain2.co.id/myimage.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' *.mydomain1.co.id:* data: blob:".
```

I use Apache web server.

Is there something wrong in the `Content-Security-Policy`? what can I do to fix this? Any suggestion will appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem. Turns out my `Content-Security-Policy` is not valid. I use [CSP Validator](https://cspvalidator.org) to validate my CSP syntax. Turns out I have to add colon (`:`) in the subdomain. Here's my final CSP for `img-src` :

```
default-src blob: http: data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' *.mysubdomain1.co.id:* *mysubdomain2.co.id:*  data: blob:
```

The above CSP fixed my problem.